# How to page changeset via TFS 2015 REST API

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to crawl the changesets from a TFS 2015 server via the API. I'm using the `$top` and `$skip` parameters to do the paging as documented. However some odd behaviours are occurring:

- Requesting 255 items returns all 255. Requesting 256 and above only returns 132.
- The Link HTTP header is not included in the response for the second page - preventing automatic crawling.
- Manually incrementing the `$skip` parameter in a browser returns zero items.

Is it possible to page items via the API or does TFS place limitations to prevent it?

Comment: Just tried it using Postman and it works in my case. Do You have Update 3 installed?

Comment: @Legends It's Update 2 (Build number: 14.95.25122.0).

Answer (score 2):

API can only return 256 changesets. So to get all of them you need to:

1) get first 256 changesets (I used orderby in case of different order in responses):

```
_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=256&orderby=id desc&searchCriteria.itemPath=<your_path>&api-version=1.0
```

2) if you have more then 0 items in response get last value of changesetNumber from response. If 0 - you got all changesets.

3) get next 256 items starting from changesetNumber:

```
 _apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.toId=<changesetNumber>&$top=256&orderby=id desc&searchCriteria.itemPath=<your_path>&api-version=1.0
```

You need to skip first changeset (you already have this value) in response.

4) go to Step 2